# REGEX Match all except what comes after key word

Tags: javascript, regex

New to Regex & Stack Overflow and finding it hard to get the hang of.

I am trying to match all text except what comes after a keyword. Here is the scraped text from a site. Javascript. Unable to get rid of whitespace. Is there a way to select all except what comes after 'Exterior Colour' for example?

I have tried looking around and have got as far as

[^((?!Engine).)*](https://regex101.com/r/sqBLlE/1)

I need to select everything apart from 'Jet Black Metallic'. Does anyone have any pointers? Would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share the sample input and output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this expression. does that answer your question?
everything prior to the 'Exterior colour' will be captured

```
(.*)Exterior Colour
```

```
https://regex101.com/r/F7zDlb/1
```

[image]

Comment: It does do the first part however I then need it to select everything after Jet Black Metallic. What would I need to input for that to happen?

Comment: @LucaAppleyard,  **(.*)Exterior Colour.*Jet Black Metallic(.*)** , this will get you two group, one prior to the *Exterior Colour* and the second capture will be after *Jet Black Metallic*. Is that what you're looking for ?   https://regex101.com/r/3iytry/1

Answer (score 0):

Try to use noncapturing group `(?:...)`.
Your paritcular regexp would looks like this `/.*?(?:Exterior Colour)/`

Link to regex: https://regex101.com/r/hG81L5/1

Comment: Thanks, this does the first part of the problem, however I then need it to select everything after the Jet Black Metallic bit. Is there a way to keep a defined number of spaces after the Exterior Colour?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's help. Managed to figure it out the formulae i was looking for is listed below.

Engine\S+.\S+.\S+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[^E]*(?:E(?!ngine)[^E]*)*